# How to display C structure in Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt, structure

In Qt debug mode, we can watch and edit any variable.
My question: is there any existing class that can do the same thing which mean can display all the members of a C structure variable in a table and can edit value of members?

Comment: what do you mean by class??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get right what you mean answer in NO. Seems to me you are looking for an ability to show any struct{} variable/array in QTableView using generic model class. That can be achieved if C++ had a mechanisms similar to Java Reflection.

In your case one of solution can be to change struct's to classes with fields defined as Q_PROPERTY. Then you can get similar behaviour. But it's all depends on what you are trying to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am doing a C/C++ mixing programming, the struct is come from C which is to realize an algorithm library for embedded system. In C++, I just want to display and edit the parameters struct for algorithm tuning. So refactor the C struct into C++ class.

Comment: sure you can do it. I would implement a QAbstractItemModel (or any of it's subclasses which you fill suitable for you) to work with structures you have, and attach it QTableView/QTreeView..

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion.